# Trying to center calendar control in visual studio c#

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, calendar

I am using visual studio and programming in c# however I am facing a problem in trying to center Calendar control in a Panel

I centered everything in the panel including radiobuttons , checkboxes , textboxes but the two calendars are stuck on the left side of the panel and I can't seem to move it anywhere else on the design page

I tried Calendar.CaptionAlign Property but it didn't seem to work

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfHB6.jpg)

Is there any helpful code I can use under

```
 protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {


 }
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us what you've done in your html or code behind?

Comment: It is empty, I didn't add any code under the Calendar1_SelectionChanged but tried adding CaptionAlign to the source, I centered everything using the html source editing toolbox (align) button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with CSS. Go to Content folder in your project and find Site.css file. Then add some CSS-class for your calendars at the bottom of this file:

```
.calendar {
    display: block; 
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Then set CssClass property of your calendars to "calendar".

Comment: @Jacob Adjust width of your component by changing width property in CSS from 200px to needed.

Comment: @Jacob You can also use more complex ways of centering things by CSS. 
A new elegant way to do this is using flex by creating container like div with "display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;" 

https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html